# EditText is a TextView when checking type

Tags: android, kotlin, casting, android-edittext

I'm using this line to check on a number of views in my app and get the values associated with them, as input by the user. Every other view (odd) is a text view that's used as a title for the following view. These are created dynamically at runtime, and so I've collected the IDs into an arrayList to use in the following loop:

```
for(id in data.orEmpty()) {
                val mView = findViewById<View>(id)
                if (mView is TextView) {
                    Log.d("BEAU - ", "WOOT! ID number $id TextView - ${mView.text}")
                }
                if (mView is EditText) {
                    Log.d("BEAU - ", "WOOT! ID number $id EditText - ${mView.text}")
                }
                if (mView is RatingBar) {
                   Log.d("BEAU - ", "WOOT! ID number $id RatingBar - ${mView.numStars}")
                }
            }
```

The problem I'm having is that every EditText is being counted as both a TextView and an EditText; and so I'll have something like this:

> D/BEAU -: WOOT! ID number 1 TextView - General EditText
>
> D/BEAU -: WOOT! ID number 2 TextView - Hello World
>
> D/BEAU -: WOOT! ID number 2 EditText - Hello World

However, all of the other things (like the rating bar) work perfectly. So, the question is, why is EditText passing a type check for text view; and is there something I can do to check for only text views and not text views and edit texts in the first if statement?

**EDIT:**

Temporarily, I've been able to check against EditTexts when checking for TextViews. I've done this like so:
`if (mView is TextView && mView !is EditText) {}`
But, is this right to do, and if so why should I have to do it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `EditText` is a subclass of `TextView`, so this will give you `true` -

```
EditText is TextView
```

In `EditText` class you can see -

```
class EditText extends TextView { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yiu need to put your chcecks in the right order. In this case as `EditText` extends `TextView`, you need to check first if this is `EditText` and then check its parent class (if you have longer inheritance chain, then you should check from the bottom of the hierarchy up to base/root class.

Answer (score 1):

If it is suitable you can compare classes instead of checking types:

```
when (view.javaClass) {
    TextView::class.java, AppCompatTextView::class.java -> {}
    EditText::class.java, AppCompatEditText::class.java -> {}
    RatingBar::class.java, AppCompatRatingBar::class.java -> {}
}
```